# Grant Exec on a set of stored procedures

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have about 500 procedures in a database that are prefixed with `mysp_`.

Currently I have two roles, `Role1` and `Role2` and permission to execute the procedures is spread amongst them.

I need to delete `Role2` (which isn't a problem), and then `Grant Exec` on every one of my procedures to `Role1`.

Can anyone advise how to do this please? I can easily `Grant` on a single procedure, but not on a selection of procedures (e.g. those prefixed with `mysp_`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use dynamic SQL and a cursor to iterate over the procedures:

```
DECLARE @ProcName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE DynamicSQL CURSOR FOR
SELECT Name FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype = 'P' and Name like 'mysp_%'

OPEN DynamicSQL

FETCH NEXT FROM DynamicSQL INTO @ProcName
WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
BEGIN

  SET @SQL = 'GRANT EXEC ON ' + @ProcName + ' TO Role1'
  PRINT @SQL
  --EXEC(@SQL)

FETCH NEXT FROM DynamicSQL INTO @ProcName
END

CLOSE DynamicSQL
DEALLOCATE DynamicSQL
```

Once you're happy with the output, just uncomment the EXEC part!

Comment: Excellent suggestion.  Just a tiny typo (`TO...` should be  ` TO...` ) ;-)

Comment: What @EvilDr means is there should be a space before the `TO` in `… + 'TO Role1'`. Otherwise `TO` becomes part of the procedure name (and you'll never be happy with the output).

Comment: Yes that is indeed what I mean.  I didn't realise SO had not formatted my second code block

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
SELECT
    'GRANT EXECUTE ON ' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id) + '.' + name + ' TO Role1'
FROM 
    sys.procedures
WHERE
    Name LIKE 'mysp%'
```

This will generate as output a list of statements, which you can copy from the output grid into a new query window and then execute - and now all your procedures are granted to `Role1` !

Comment: Like it!  Does `GRANT` require `GO` or can it be terminated with `;`?

Comment: @EvilDr: I think a semicolon `;` should be sufficient